# Is there a point to having Windows manage the page file size and have a "dedicated" swap drive

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, memory, virtual-memory, pagefile

On a SQL 2008R2 box we recently had a number of jobs fails for various reasons that were mostly memory related, including one stating the page file was full. The Windows 2008R2 VM had 16GB of RAM and a dedicated disk for a 6GB page file. For now we moved the page file back to the C: drive and increased its size to 8GB. The long term effects of that are yet to be seen.

Our Server Admin, this morning, increased that "swap" drive to 25GB as was recommended by the GUI. What struck me as odd is that the admin also changed virtual memory to be mananged automatically across all drives. This strikes me as waste of space but I don't really understand how Windows automatically manages the page file. Here is a snapshot of the current virtual memory settings to help with the description.

[image: Virtual memory settings]

Can a Windows OS that is automatically managing paging file size for all drives effectively use a drive that is dedicated for that purpose?

Answer (score 2):

To allow windows to manage the pagefile size but only use the S: (swap) dedicated volume:

- Uncheck the "Automatically manage paging file size for all drives" check box.
- Highlight the "C:" volume, and select the "No paging file" radio button and click the "Set" button
- Highlight the "S:" volume and select the "System managed size" radio button and click "Set"

Comment: So it was a mistake and it was set up incorrectly. Makes sense when it gets pointed out to me but I could not see it even though it was staring me in the face.

Comment: Updated my reply to remove some possible erroneous info. Technically, I think Windows might spill over and create multiple page files on the other drives but it would be using all the drives and will usually put the bulk of the page file on the system drive.

Comment: I didn't think it was smart enough to know to use that space effectively. That screen shot is post reboot as well if it matters. Either way I got the information I wanted. If there was something authoritative for your last comment I would love to read it (unless its too long :().